# Windows 10 - external display remains an extended desktop after input is changed away from the PC

Tags: windows-10, external-display

My setup:

1. HP Spectre Laptop, running Windows 10 Pro with all the latest updates
2. Plugable Triple-Monitor docking station: [https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Charging-Delivery-Specific-Thunderbolt/dp/B01FKTZLBS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FKTZLBS) running the latest DisplayLink drivers
3. 2 HP 23' Monitors
4. 1 TCL 43" LCD TV

I run the setup with the laptop closed - the two HDMI ports on the Plugable dock go to each of the HP monitors, and the DVI port goes to an HDMI port of Input 2 on the TV.  I'm running extended desktop mode.

When I switch the TV away from Input 2 to a different input, Windows 10 still recognizes it as an external display, which is unwanted behavior for several reasons.  Clearly, just switching away from the input does not truly disconnect the communication between the TV and Windows.

I'm trying to figure out if there's is a way to accomplish this disconnection, either in the TV settings, in Windows, or via some 3rd party software helper app.

Comment: “Clearly, just switching away from the input does not truly disconnect the communication between the TV and Windows.” – No, of course. That’s expected behavior with pretty much any display. I’m afraid you won’t be able to change that, except perhaps with using a HDMI switch with one output disconnected.

Comment: Hi Daniel. That is expected behavior?  My HP monitors have two HDMI inputs on them.  If you have two HDMI sources plugged in - when you switch to one, it disconnects the other - I was hoping to achieve this behavior with the TV.  Perhaps there is such an HDMI switch built-in to the HP monitors which is why it works at desired. Thanks your for your input in any case.

Comment: Do you know if any of the multi-monitor management apps (i.e UltraMon, DisplayFusion, etc) allow you to do anything like manually disconnect the display from within Windows 10?

Comment: Sure, UltraMon can do [that](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp). Windows can too. Nothing is forcing your PC do display an image on all connected displays.